# Layout BorderPane JavaFX

Tags: javafx, borderpane

I'm creating an JavaFX Game like "Wheel of Fortune". I use a BorderPane as root of the scene. and the right of this pane is set to contain a GridPane which in turn contain an ImageView and some other elements. I want to set the position of the ImageView (the wheel) so that only half of it is displayed. I've setLayoutX and setLayoutY to set the position of ImageView with x = X of GridPane + ImageView. X /2 (something like that), but the ImageView is not placed as expected. How should I do that???

[ImageView http://imageshack.com/a/img812/6161/ynb8.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img812/6161/ynb8.png)

Comment: Check the Node#setClip() out.

Comment: Did you try to use setTranslateX and setTranslateY instead of setLayoutX, setLayoutY ?

Comment: @Daniel yeah, you're right. I solved this problem with setTranslateX and setTranslateY